# Finding a subset of numbers that will give you the max sum

Tags: math, max, primes, combinatorics, subset-sum

How to find a subset of numbers from 2 to 1000 that will give you the max sum under the condition that any two numbers from the subset don't share common prime factors (e.g., 1000 and 500 share the prime factor 2)?

One (maybe easier) variation to the above question: what is the largest number in the subset? We know that 997 is a prime number, and it is easy to rule out 1000 and 998, thus the question becomes whether is 999 in the subset?

Comment: this is a hard problem. You should make use of dynamic programming techniques here. You can't know if you're choosing the right numbers until you have got to the end of the algorithm, so you need to find ways to eliminate numbers from the possible choices before choosing them and calculating a new sum. But to start, you can begin selecting all prime numbers from `sqrt(1000)` to `1000`, and then compare only the ones that aren't in that set.

Comment: "it is easy to rule out 1000 and 998" really? why?

Comment: @Henrik: because they share a common factor, namely 2.

Comment: The [euclidean algorithm for the greatest common divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm) is a fast algorithm for determining if any two integers share a common factor. You are looking for a subset of pairwise relatively prime integers for which the sum is maximized. One such set is obvious: the set of all primes in [2...1000]. Note that using the euclidean algorithm may not be optimal for this problem; depending on your solution it may be better simply to factor each integer completely using a sieve.

Comment: @Henrik: 1000=2^3 * 5^3, but 512 + 625 > 1000; 998=2*499, but 512 + 499 > 1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a graph with nodes {2, ...,  1000}, and edges when nodes have gcd > 1. Solution to this problem is same as finding [maximum-weight independent set problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)), which is NP-hard except in some special cases. This graph case doesn't look like a spacial case from list on Wikipedia page or even on this [list](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/problem_Weighted_independent_set.html).

**Update**

As James suggested it is possible to reduce number of nodes in this graph. Lets say that signature of a number N with prime decomposition `p1^k1*...*pn^kn` is a tuple `(p1, ..., pn)`.

First reduction is to remove nodes when there is nodes with larger value and same signature. That reduces graph to 607 nodes.

Next reduction is to remove node `N` with signature `(p1, ..., pn)` if there are nodes with signatures that is decomposition of `(p1, ..., pn)` and there sum is `>= N`. That reduces graph to 277 nodes.

From these nodes 73 are isolated nodes (primes > 500.)

Comment: Edges between what?

Comment: @JamesKPolk edges between nodes. E.g. there is an edge between every pair of nodes with even value, like 1000 and 998.

Comment: This seems correct, +1. I've been playing around with python igraph and it seems that the size of this graph is too large to solve on my macbook, whereas the same problem with nodes  {2, 3, ..., 300} is solvable with about 6 mins of CPU and 6 GB of memory. If there was some logic to a-priori decide which even number is in the max sum we could immediately eliminate at least half the nodes.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Good idea with elimination. If we have node N with value p_1^k_1 * ... * p_n^k_n, where p's are primes and k's >= 1. Than there is no need for nodes with same primes in decomposition where all k_i are less or equal than in N, but >= 1, and one is strictly less. Like, there is no need for 256 if we have 512. Or there is no need for 6 if we have 12 or 18.

Comment: @JamesKPolk This reduction will leave 168 numbers of type p^k, 288 numbers of type p1^k1*p2^k2, 135 nodes with three primes, and 16 nodes with 4 primes. That is 607 nodes, where 73 nodes are not connected at all (primes > 500). Graph will be sparser than original, which can gain speedup.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Once more :-) One more optimization. There is no need for node N=p1^k1*...*pn^kn (like 1000=2^3*5^3) if there are nodes p1^l1*...*pi^li and p(i+1)^l(i+1)*...*pn^ln with sum >=N (2^9=512 and 5^4=625). Similar for N with more primes in decomposition. That will eliminate for sure all number with 4 primes, probably all with 3 primes, and I think lot of them with 2 primes.

Comment: Any more optimizations? I have implemented all the optimizations here and used dynamic programming, and it took me almost 3hrs and about 30GB memory to calculate the result when N=900, but when N=1000, after it took me more than 10hrs, it said the memory was not enough and the program crashed...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to this, it seems non-trivial to me. Here are a few thoughts.

The sum consists of a variable number of summands, say s<sub>0</sub> + s<sub>1</sub> + ... s<sub>k</sub>, where s<sub>i</sub> is an integer in the interval [2, 1000]. Now each s<sub>i</sub> has a prime-power factorization s<sub>i</sub>=(p<sub>1</sub><sup>e1</sup>)*(p<sub>2</sub><sup>e2</sup>) ... where e<sub>i</sub> ≥ 1.

The condition that "that any two numbers from the subset don't share common prime factors" is equivalent to stating that s<sub>i</sub> are pairwise relatively prime, i.e. gcd(s<sub>i</sub>, s<sub>j</sub>)=1 for i ≠ j. Also equivalently, whenever one summand s<sub>i</sub> contains a prime p that means that no other summand may contain that prime.

So how do you arrange the primes into summands? One simple rule is immediately obvious. All the primes in [500, 1000] can only appear in the sum alone as individual summands. If they are multiplied by anything else, even the smallest prime 2, the product will be too large. So that leaves the task of arranging the smaller primes. And I don't know they best way to do that. For the sake of completeness I'll provide the following short python program that shows one way.

```py
def sieve_prime_set(n):
    # sieve[i] = set(p1, p2, ...pn) for each prime p_i that divides i.

    sieve = [set() for i in range(n + 1)]
    primes = []
    next_prime = 1
    while True:
        # find the next prime
        for i in range(next_prime + 1, len(sieve)):
            if not sieve[i]:
                next_prime = i
                break
        else:
            break

        primes.append(next_prime)
        # sieve out by this prime
        for kp in range(next_prime, n + 1, next_prime):
            sieve[kp].add(next_prime)

    return sieve, primes

def max_sum_strategy1(sieve):
    last = len(sieve) - 1
    summands = [last]
    max_sum = last
    prime_set = sieve[last]
    while last >= 2:
        last -= 1
        if not sieve[last] & prime_set:
            max_sum += last
            prime_set |= sieve[last]
            summands.append(last)

    return max_sum, summands, prime_set

def max_sum_strategy2(primes, n):
    return sum(p ** int(log(n, p)) for p in primes)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sieve, primes = sieve_prime_set(1000)
    max_sum, _, _ = max_sum_strategy1(sieve)
    print(max_sum)
    print(max_sum_strategy2(primes, 1000))
```

Output is

```
84972
81447
```

showing that "strategy 1" is superior.

Superior, but not necessarily optimal. For example, including 1000 seems good, but it forces us to exclude every other even summand and every summand divisible by 5. If we leave 1000 out but include 998 instead, we get to use another summand that includes 5 in it's prime factorization. But including 998 forces other summands to be excluded. So maximizing the sum is not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python script to solve the problem. It takes a couple of minutes to run on my laptop.

```py
import math
import networkx as nx

max_number = 1000

G = nx.Graph()

for i in range(2, max_number + 1):
    G.add_node(i, weight=i)

for i in range(2, max_number + 1):
    for j in range(i+1, max_number + 1):
        if math.gcd(i, j) == 1:
            G.add_edge(i, j)

numbers, sum_of_numbers = nx.max_weight_clique(G)

print(sorted(numbers))
print(sum_of_numbers)
```

The list of numbers returned is shown below; the total is 85684. (There may be other valid sets of numbers that give this total.)

```py
[41, 59, 67, 71, 79, 83, 97, 101, 103, 107, 113, 127, 131, 137, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 841, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 893, 901, 907, 911, 919, 925, 929, 937, 941, 947, 949, 953, 961, 967, 971, 973, 976, 977, 979, 981, 983, 989, 991, 997]
```